# I get error 9 subscript out of range when ever i try to run this "file match" code

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am very new to Vba and coding in general, so please excuse any mistake I may have made. I keep getting a run time error "subscript out of range". This code is meant to work in conjunction with the first module that I wrote, which works fine, but I need to verify that this works first before I integrate it. This code is meant to find what is referred to as an "h-number", then match that h number to a list generated by the first module, then it will copy certain dates corresponding to the h number back to the current workbook (I have a place holder code for the time being). My Code:

```
Sub filematcher()
Dim Activesource As Workbook 'saves file so that it can be refrenced in code
Dim AOI2 As Range


Call OptimizeCode_Begin
'opens the file

Set Activesource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\ebecerra\Desktop\active status sheet 
 copy for macro.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

Set AOI2 = Activesource.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A")

For Each cell In AOI2
    On Error Resume Next
    H_source = cell.Value
    'matches the H number found to the one on the master sheet
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("A")
            Set H_match = .Find(H_source, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                On Error Resume Next
        End With
    'find the row number that coresponds to the found h-number
    Y_Match = H_match.Row
    'records the found h number to verify that code works
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Cells(Y_Match, H).Value = H_source
    
Next cell
  
Activesource.Close savechanges:=False
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle_2
ErrorHandle_2:
        Set Activesource = Nothing
 
'End optimizer
 Call OptimizeCode_End

 End Sub
```

IF it matters this is the code optimizer as well as the first module that I mentioned:

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean
 Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
 End Sub
 Sub OptimizeCode_End()

  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
  Application.Calculation = CalcState
  Application.EnableEvents = EventState
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub

 Sub collectdata()

Dim MyFSO As New FileSystemObject 'declaring and initializing FSO (file system object)
Dim wkbsource As Workbook 'workbook variable to store the raw excel file
Dim iRow As Long ' to store the last blank row available in collected data sheet before pasting the raw data
Dim iTotalRow As Long 'to store the last non-blank row availbe in collected data sheet after pasting the raw data
Dim sPath As String ' to store the selected folder path
Dim SourceFolder As Folder 'to store folder path
Dim MyFile As File 'File variable for FSO
Dim Filename As String ' to store the excel file name for column A in collected data sheet
Dim iTotalFiles As Long 'to store the count of all excel files available in selected folder
Dim DialogBox As FileDialog 'file dialog to select the folder name
Dim Hours As Range 'To store the Hours of test ran
Dim IRtestdate As Range 'To store the date of the IR reading
Dim iFailsRow As Long 'to identify the last cell used, therefore identifies how many pcs ran
Dim Count As Long 'To store the amount of bad pcs
Dim AOI As Range 'To determine the area for which the program will look for bad pcs

'Begin Optimizer
Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Set DialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Assiging Folder picker dialog box
With DialogBox
    .Title = "Select Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'no folder selected
    sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'Check wheather selected folder exists or not
If Not MyFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
    MsgBox "folder is not available.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    appication.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Set SourceFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
'Get the count of all excel files available in Sourcefolder (selected folder)
iTotalFiles = 0 

For Each MyFile In SourceFolder.Files
    If MyFSO.GetExtensionName(MyFile) = "xls" Then
        iTotalFiles = iTotalFiles + 1
    End If
Next MyFile

'Code to terminate the code if there is no Excel file availbe in Selected folder
If iTotalFiles = 0 Then

    MsgBox "no Excelfile available.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
    
End If

'Code to compile the data from Raw file to collecter
For Each MyFile In SourceFolder.Files

    If MyFSO.GetExtensionName(MyFile) = "xls" Then
    
'Code to identify the last Blank row number in collated data sheet
        iRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        
'Store the file name
        Filename = MyFSO.GetFileName(MyFile)
        
'Code to open the raw file
        Set wkbsource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error GoTo Nextloop
'finds out if the file belongs to Jeff, if not it skips the file
         Set requester = wkbsource.ActiveSheet.Range("F3")
         If requester.Value = "Jeff Horn" Then
              GoTo Valid
         Else
              GoTo Nextloop
        End If
 Valid:
        
'code to identify If the Sheet is Blank
        If IsEmpty(wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("N23").Value) = True Then GoTo Nextloop
       
'finds Group number and pastes to collated sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("B" & iRow) = wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("F2")
        
'finds Test ran and pastes to collated sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("C" & iRow) = wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("B1")
        
        
'Code to read the hours ran, find the highest value, and display it in the Collated data sheet
            With wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("M21:T21")
                
                Set Hours = .Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                   
            End With
                If Hours Is Nothing Then
                GoTo Testdate
                Else: On Error GoTo Testdate
                End If
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("D" & iRow) = Hours
                
                
 Testdate:
   
'Finds the the IRtestdate and Pastes that value into the Collated data sheet
                With wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("M18:T18")
                
                    Set IRtestdate = .Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                   
                End With
                If IRtestdate Is Nothing Then
                GoTo FailsCounter
                Else: On Error GoTo FailsCounter
                End If
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("E" & iRow) = IRtestdate
                    
  FailsCounter:
'code to identify the column that needs to be counted dynamically based on Hours tested
                
            iFailsRow = wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Y = Hours.Row + 2
            X = Hours.Column
            Count = 0
            Set AOI = wkbsource.Sheets("Uncorrected").Range(Cells(Y, X), Cells(iFailsRow, X))
'Code to count the number of fails in each file
            For Each cell In AOI
               If cell.Value <= 0.001 Then
                    Count = Count + 1
                    On Error Resume Next
               End If
             Next
        Total_Parts = iFailsRow - 22
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("F" & iRow) = Count & " of " & Total_Parts
        
'Code to identify the last non-blank row in collated data sheet after pasting raw data
                    
        iTotalRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
'Code to update the file name
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Collated Data").Range("A" & iRow & ":A" & iTotalRow).Value = Filename
        
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Nextloop:
        wkbsource.Close savechanges:=False
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
  ErrorHandle:
        Set wkbsource = Nothing
    End If
Next MyFile

MsgBox "Data collated", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done!"

'End optimizer
Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Set Activesource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\ebecerra\Desktop\active status sheet 
 copy for macro.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
this one^ but sometimes its the next line

Comment: That error means there's no "Sheet 1" in `Activesource`  You can use `Activesource.Worksheets(1)` instead if you just want the first worksheet.

Comment: Shouldn't `Activesource.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A")` be `Activesource.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A:A")`?

Comment: im able to get the file open but when the code gets to `Set AOI2 = Activesource.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A")` i get an error 1004. ive tried replacing the `sheet 1` to `activesheet` but still i get the same error.